# Unable to remove 'residual config' packages in Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: synaptic

I am using 11.04 with Synaptic Package Manager (Ver 0.70). When I select **Status** and try to delete packages from the **Not Installed (residual config)** option, although I can select these old applications (such as Banshee and Evolution which I don't use) and **mark for removal**, the **Apply** button is not active and remains greyed out. I assume that I am administrator as I am the only user of the machine and can use `sudo` in terminal. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

[That is a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/754297). You can remove the residual config files without synaptic using this handy one-liner:

```
aptitude -F %p search '~c' | xargs sudo dpkg -P
```

You may have to install [aptitude](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=aptitude) if you haven't done that yet.

Comment: `sudo aptitude purge ~c` is more than enough.

Comment: @karel should my script remove those icons instead? I don't know what common practice is on Ask Ubuntu these days - the script is just trying to restore the original post.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for writing such a useful script. I don't see the necessity of restoring the formatting of the original post, so I would personally recommend modifying your script for cases like this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have sudo privileges, try:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge banshee evolution`

It should do the same thing as what you would do in Synaptic. You can do this for all packages with remaining configs.