# "Apply" button stays grey in Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: synaptic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to remove 'residual config' packages in Synaptic Package Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57476/unable-to-remove-residual-config-packages-in-synaptic-package-manager)

I am trying to get rid of old residual config package with `Synaptic Package Manager` by following this [link](http://maketecheasier.com/8-ways-to-maintain-a-clean-lean-ubuntu-machine/2008/10/07). It is strange that after `select “Mark for complete removal”` for some packages, the `Apply` button of the tool stays still grey, I could not click on it...

Could anyone help? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

is a synaptic known bug please simply select an app to install and you can apply changes

Comment: Thanks for your reply... But could you please elaborate a little bit? What does "select an app to install" mean?

Comment: Simply force to install an application...